# Switch on a string skips all cases

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
            Console.WriteLine(used+ "\n"+ extracted[used]);
            switch (extracted[used])
            {
                case "*": result = number1 * number2; break;
                case "/": result = number1 / number2; break;
                case "+": result = number1 + number2; break;
                case "-": result = number1 - number2; break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Error - Could not assign starting value."); break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Marker 3");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This snippet produces the output:

1

+

Error - Could not assign starting value.

Marker 3

0

Why does this happen? In the second row of the output, the program prints out that the value of extracted[used] is "+", yet the switch statement fails to go to case "+", instead going to default, and printing out the error, and then printing out the placeholder value for "result". If it matters, extracted is an array of strings.

Comment: Can you use instead `Console.WriteLine(used + "\n<<<" + extracted[used] + ">>>")` to see if there are any spaces around that value?

Comment: any spaces or other characters around the plus? try `Console.WriteLine(used+ "\n*"+ extracted[used] + "*");`

Comment: Could you post the content of the array that produces the problem?

Comment: Ya, it looks like there's an extra new-line between the '+' and "Error - ..." which wouldn't be there if extracted[used] was just "+"

Comment: Yup, Console.WriteLine(used + "\n<<<" + extracted[used] + ">>>") showed me a bunch of spaces after what looked like a lone "+". Thanks guys!

Comment: Incomprehensible. Since your 'output' does not start with 'used' it is not from the code snippet. And we don't know what extracted and used are. One consolation: the switch statement is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching over `extracted[used].Trim()` and you'll get the correct switch to be hit.

```
Console.WriteLine(used+ "\n<<<"+ extracted[used] + ">>>");
switch (extracted[used].Trim())
{
    case "*": result = number1 * number2; break;
    case "/": result = number1 / number2; break;
    case "+": result = number1 + number2; break;
    case "-": result = number1 - number2; break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("Error - Could not assign starting value."); break;
}
Console.WriteLine("Marker 3");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the second row of the output does not show you extracted[used] is equal to "+", but that it looks like it. I would not be surprised at all if there were some unseen white spaces in extract[used]...

You should debug your program to be sure of the value of extracted[used] instead of trusting what you see in WriteLine.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code, and it works as expected.  So the problem must be with the value of `extracted[used]`.

```
static int binary_op(int n1, int n2, string op)
{
  int result;
  switch (op)
  {
    case "*":
      result = n1 * n2;
      break;
    case "/":
      result = n1 / n2;
      break;
    case "+":
      result = n1 + n2;
      break;
    case "-":
      result = n1 - n2;
      break;
    default:
      throw new Exception("invalid operation");
  }
  return result;
}
```

You invoke it like this:

```
binary_op(2, 2, "+");  // => 4
```

It might be a good idea to break this logic out into its own function in your code.   You can test that function independently, and then when it breaks when called from elsewhere in your code, you will know that the problem is in the calling code.